# object reference not set to an instance of an object--

Tags: reference

`object reference not set to an instance of an object--`

Please help me resolving this error. Is there a mistake in my syntax?

```
string filename = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
FileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/Uploads/") + filename);
```

I am having a problem in the first line

Comment: This is a typical runtime error, not a syntax error, probably either `FileUpload1`, `FileUpload.PostedFile` or `FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName` is not initialized. Also, please provide more meaningful tags, what language is this?

Answer (score 0):

well you have not mentioned any language and platform. But seems that you are working on asp.net here is VB code to help you.

```
 Sub SubmitButton_Click(Source As Object, e As EventArgs)
   If Not (File1.PostedFile Is Nothing) Then
      Try
         File1.PostedFile.SaveAs("C:\Uploads\uploadedfile.txt")
         Span1.InnerHtml = "Upload Successful!"
      Catch ex As Exception
           ex.ToString()
      End Try
   End If
End Sub
```